# Can the order of $2$ $mod {}$ an odd number that is a factor of $p-1$ be a multiple of the order of $2$ $mod$ $p$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Is there some odd prime $p$ and odd number $q$ such that $q|p-1$ and $ord_{p}(2)|ord_{q}(2)$? I'm fairly sure there isn't, so I'm mostly looking for a proof of that, although a counterexample would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $q=5, p=31$ works, I think.

Comment: I don't think so - $ord_{5}(2)=4$, $ord_{31}(2)=5$?  Unless I'm seriously misunderstanding something.

Comment: @Mindlack No, $ord_{31}(2)=5$ and $ord_5(2)=4$.

Comment: In fact a Mersenne prime cannot work as we then have $p=2^k-1$ and $ord_p(2)=k$ and $q\mid 2^{k-1}-1$ and $ord_q(2)\le k-1$.

Comment: Right, I was mistaken, thanks.

Comment: @David how do you get from $q | 2^{k-1} - 1$ to $ord_{q}(2) <= k-1$?

Comment: Definition of order: it is the **smallest** $m$ such that $q\mid 2^m-1$.

Comment: Oh, of course.  I didn't think of using larger divisibility values to set an upper bound.

Comment: @TheZachMan Isn't the notation $ord_2(p)$, if we want to find the smallest positive $k$ with $2^k\equiv 1\mod p$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are examples : One of it is $$p=251$$ $$q=125$$ With the following PARI/GP - program you can search for more examples :

```
? forprime(p=3,10^4,fordiv(p-1,q,if(Mod(q,2)<>0,if(Mod(znorder(Mod(2,q)),znorder
(Mod(2,p)))==0,print([p,q])))))
[251, 125]
[1459, 729]
[5419, 301]
[5419, 387]
[5419, 903]
[5419, 2709]
?
```

By replacing "10^4" by a larger value, you can find even more examples.

Comment: That's interesting that the lowest two both have $q = k^{3}$ and each $p$ that works works with $p-1/2$